# Rails form - how to send in the input an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, forms, input

I have the array

> params[:search][:cars]

which contains

```
"search"=>{"cars"=>["11", "7"]}
```

this array I am trying to put into the hidden of a form field (this block of code is in the helper method):

```
...
data += hidden_field_tag 'search[cars]', params[:search][:cars]
...
return data.html_safe
```

and this form after sending gives me:

```
"search"=>{"cars"=>"[\"11\", \"7\"]"}
```

I would like to ask you about the help, how can I send an array through the hidden input.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view (adapt it to use in your helper) you can write:

```
<% params[:search][:cars].each do |car_id| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'search[cars][]', car_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes, I know about this option, but there I have to go loop through the entire array again... and it take some time. Doesn't exist any way, how to put there already existed array via input?

Comment: AFAIK this is the only serialization that Rails implements for forms. You'll need to manually decode it in the controller/model if you choose another way.